# Raspberry Pi 2 Model B is preventing my def function

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

I have a raspberry Pi 2 Model B. I am trying to make a program that turns on an LED when the input is 'Yes'. What happens is that I get a syntax error saying that def was the error with the arrow pointing at the f. Here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(38, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(38, 1)

def start():
    main(input("> ")

def main(yn):
    while True:
        if yn == 'Yes':
            GPIO.output(40, 1)
            print("The LED is on!")
            break
        if yn == 'No':
            GPIO.output(40, 0)
            print("The LED is off!")
            break
    start()
start()
```

Please help and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `start` function is missing a closing parenthesis:

```
def start():
    main(input("> "))
```

Comment: Thank you! I am an idiot sometimes... :)